# How to define a function that calculate the sum of all leaves in a binary number tree in python?

Tags: python, function, binary-tree

Just like ((1,(2,3)),4)

how can I get the sum of all the leaves through a defined function? like 1+2+3+4?

My function is like following but still getting an error and I just confused and no idea with this.

```
def add_leaves(tree):
    """returns to the sum of all the numbers in the binary-number-tree
    bin -> int"""
    if not isinstance(tree,tuple):
        return tree[0] + tree[1]
    else:
        return add_leaves(tree[0]) + add_leaves(tree[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution that will do this for any n-ary tree (instead of just a binary tree). This will also work for arbitrary leaves, instead of just full trees.

```
def add_leaves(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    else:
        return sum(add_leaves(i) for i in x)

>>> tree = ((1,(2,3)),4)
>>> add_leaves(tree)
10
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using for your base case is wrong. The `isinstance` call will be `False` when the function is passed a leaf value (an `int`), but you're still trying to index that value. You should just return the `tree` in that case:

```
def add_leaves(tree):
    """returns to the sum of all the numbers in the binary-number-tree
    bin -> int"""
    if not isinstance(tree,tuple):
        return tree                                         # fix is here!
    else:
        return add_leaves(tree[0]) + add_leaves(tree[1])
```

Comment: For what its worth, this will only work for [full](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) binary trees. If a node doesn't have exactly two leaves, the code will fail with an `index out of range` error

Comment: That's true, but since the values are only in the leaves, there's no reason to expect there to be any half-full nodes.

Comment: I just meant something like this `(,((1,(2,3)),4))`, note that at the top level, the left leaf is empty

Comment: That's invalid syntax though. A value in a Python tuple can't be "empty", it needs to be something. Perhaps `None` would make sense in that situation, but nothing doesn't work.